# Remove 'p' tags v from images function query

Tags: php, image, wordpress

I found a solution to remove to the p tags from images when creating a post which works however only for one image.

For the image that it works for, i looked at firebug and this is what is shown:

```
<div class="entry-content">
<a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/img-1.png">
<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-50" width="520" height="320" src="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/img-1.png" alt="img-1">
</a>
```

and so on....great!

But when i upload another image to another post this happens:

```
<p>
<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-50" width="520" height="320" src="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/img-1.png" alt="img-1">
<br>
Lorem ipsum dolo....
</p>
```

This is the function i'm using in my functions file:

```
<?php
function filter_ptags_on_images($content){
    return preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<a .*>)?\s*(<img .* \/>)\s*(<\/a>)?\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1\2\3', $content);
}
add_filter('the_content', 'filter_ptags_on_images');
?>
```

So is there a way off adding another "return line" with a function of removing the p tags when its just

as it only seems to work when its

..? I hope this makes sense! If it helps this is my css for my images:

```
width:100%;
height:auto;
min-width:320px;
}
```

I just want the image to be the full width of my post and the content to use the paragraph tags, as i say it worked for my first image but not for any others!

Thanks

Comment: are u using tiny mce?

Comment: Nope i'm not using that, is that something that can help the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress adds `<p>` tags amongst other when you run it through the content filter. If you don't want any extra tags, just don't run it through any filter at all, or look up a filter you think you can use here in the filter documentation.

I think your solution is fine, but I think your regex only takes the first occurance. Try using `preg_match_all` for your regex.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference

Comment: Yeah your right only taking the first occurrence! I have tried using preg_match_all for the function and my post content disappears and turns to a 0. For the: '/<p>\s*(<a .*>)?\s*(<img .* \/>)\s*(<\/a>)?\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1\2\3'  ... what characters do i need to remove to test if for <p><img> intsead of <p><img><a>? Ive tried solutions and nothing changes